# How exactly does the "Tearing" property work?

Tags: weapons, rogue-trader, dark-heresy-1e, deathwatch, only-war

There is some ambiguity in the **Tearing** property.

The Dark Heresy Rulebook states that:

> These weapons roll two dice for Damage and choose the highest.

Rogue Trader, Deathwatch and Only War are agreed that:

> These weapons roll one extra die for damage, and the lowest result is discarded.

For most weapons it's quite simple because of damage like **1d10+something**. But what if we have more dice in the damage roll? Should I roll an additional die for every base damage die, or only one for the entire damage roll?

For example, the **Angelus** bolter from the Dark Heresy supplement Inquisitor's Handbook has **2d10** damage and (like all bolt weapons) the **Tearing** quality. Let's presume that my character shot a heretic with this bolter, and now I must determine inflicted damage. Should I roll 2d10 twice, and discard lowest in both, or I should roll 3d10, and discard the lowest one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tearing weapons roll an extra dice in addition to however many dice are required for the weapon and then the dice with the lowest result is discarded.

> For example, the Angelus bolter from the Dark Heresy supplement Inquisitor's Handbook has 2d10 damage and (like all bolt weapons) the Tearing quality. Let's presume that my character shot a heretic with this bolter, and now I must determine inflicted damage. Should I roll 2d10 twice, and discard lowest in both, or I should roll 3d10, and discard the lowest one?

For this weapon you would roll 3d10 and discard the lowest.

Example: 
Bob the Marine shoots Eric the Heretek with his Angelus bolter and hits. This weapon does 2d10 tearing damage. Bob's player rolls 3d10 to determine damage and gets a 3, 5 and 8. The 3 is discarded making 5+8 = 13 damage. Eric is going to be unhappy.

Answer (score 8):

The [errata](https://images-cdn.fantasyflightgames.com/ffg_content/dark-heresy/pdf/darkheresy-errata-v3.0.pdf) for Dark Heresy 1e states

> The entry for Tearing on page 129 should read: “Tearing weapons are
>   vicious devices, often using multitudes of fast-moving jagged teeth or
>   fragmented or explosive ammunition to rip into flesh and bone. **These
>   weapons roll one extra die for damage, and the lowest result is
>   discarded**.”